# Azure CentOS web root folder folder permission issue

Tags: azure, centos, lamp

I am able to login to my SSH account, then while creating a file in the location /var/www/html it give me permission error . It seems that the owner of this folder is root. How can I able to get access to this folder to upload files ?

Comment: has nothing to do with azure

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, if you want to upload your files to Azure VM, you could upload files to your /home/user's folder, then copy them to /var/www/html.

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.